# On a Linux system, see how busy is file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, performance, monitoring

I want to know of a command that will show me how (currently) busy is the file system. I'm assuming there exists such a command that will show me this. With such command, are there specific arguments that I should know about? Also, is there a separate command that will tell me what the load average is?

How do I do this (using Linux)?

Comment: Modifying a question in such a way as to substantially change its meaning (for instance, from filesystem load to load in general) is not considered good behavior once answers already exist.

Comment: This already has a bunch of decent answers, I'd rather not delete it. You can post your intended question separately if you want

Answer (score 11):

- `vmstat 1` will poll overall information every second, including IO load (see the `bi` and `bo` columns for input and output).
- `iostat 1` will provide information more directly focused on IO.
- `iotop` will provide this information on a per-process level, assuming a modern kernel with appropriate configuration ([see home page](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/)).
- `dstat` is a swiss-army-knife tool combining information available from many of the above.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on what filesystem you use.
Like zfs has his own tool but in general iostat can do this.
Try:
`#man iostat` or `iostat --help`

On my OSX i can use:

`#iostat -w 1`

This will refresh every second and show u the disk iops.
Hope this is the answer your looking for. ;-)

Comment: Does `iostat` allow you to see the load average?

Comment: Yes on my MacAir "OSX" it does. And on BSD/Linux it should be too.
iostat shows:  disk, cpu, load average

Comment: I guess its different on Linux. Whenever I try it on Ubuntu I do not get the same output as when I try it on OS X. I get: avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle. And also: 
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn

Answer (score 3):

You could try `iotop`

Should be installable via a packagemanager of your choice